# How to add css on one of the selected tile in kendomultiselect in angular

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui

In my Angular 6 App I am using kendo multiselect, When I select values from the dropdown, they appear in the multiselect field. But I want to remove the (x)- close icon just for one of the values.

I tried with just css:

```
#problemWith .k-button:first-child .k-icon.k-i-close {
    display: none !important;
}
```

But this removes the close icon (x) for the very first tile. Is there anyway to apply css based on text!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to remove the `:first-child` from the css selector

Comment: That's what I've tried above! The element can be in the middle also, not always first!

Comment: remove `:first-child` from `#problemWith .k-button:first-child .k-icon.k-i-close {`

Comment: It applies to all elements in the tile. I guess the solution would be to have some kind of check in ts file (to know the index of the element for which we don't want (x) icon) and then pass it to nth child css property. So that only that element takes the css. Figuring out a way to do it.